# Why can't weka correctly predict the values of my test-set?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, svm

Why can't weka correctly predict the values of my test-set?

commands used:

```
weka -c 'weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -no-cv -t triggering.arff -d triggering.model'
weka -c 'weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -p 0 -T triggering-new.arff -l triggering.model'
```

trainning-data:

```
@relation triggering

@attribute iota real
@attribute A{TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute B{TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute C{TRUE, FALSE}

@data
10, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
20, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
30, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
40, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE
50, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE
```

test-data:

```
@relation triggering-new

@attribute iota real
@attribute A{TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute B{TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute C{TRUE, FALSE}

@data
10, ?, ?, ?
20, ?, ?, ?
30, ?, ?, ?
```

prediction:

```
=== Predictions on test data ===

 inst#     actual  predicted error prediction
     1        1:?    2:FALSE       1
     2        1:?    2:FALSE       1
     3        1:?    2:FALSE       1
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean the test set not the training set since that is the output you have provided here.  The test set data does not have attribute values.  If you are trying to predict the value of A given B and C you have to supply B and C in the test data set.

Comment: I'm trying to predict the value of A, B, and C given iota.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have instances in your test set (fill up the value of the first three instances of each attribute), and only keep only the class empty.

Regards,
Leonardo